# Global variables and local variables in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, global-variables

I have global variables and want to use them within a function.

I don't use local variables with the same name within the functions!

```powershell
# Global variables:
$Var1 = @{ .. }
$Var2 = @( .. )
function testing{
    $Var1.keyX = "kjhkjh"
    $Var2[2]   = 6.89768
}
```

I do it and it works, but is it safe or do I have to use the following?

```powershell
$Global:Var1.keyX = "kjhkjh"
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In your function, you are modifying the contents of the hashtable so there is no need to use $global unless your function (or a function caller between your function and global scope) happens to have local variables $Var1 and $Var2 (BTW aren't you missing `$`).  If this is all your own code then I'd say leave it as is.  However, if you code allows other folks' code to call your function, then I would use the `$global:Var1` specifier to make sure you're accessing the global variable and not inadvertently accessing a variable of the same name within a function that is calling your function.

Another thing to know about dynamic scoping in PowerShell is that when you assign a value to variable in a function and that variable happens to be a global e.g.:

```
$someGlobal = 7
function foo { $someGlobal = 42; $someGlobal }
foo
$someGlobal
```

PowerShell will do a "copy-on-write" operation on the variable $someGlobal within the function.  If your intent was to really modify the global then you would use the `$global:` specifier:

```
$someGlobal = 7
function foo { $global:someGlobal = 42; $someGlobal }
foo
$someGlobal
```

Comment: Thank you Keith (I changed my typo)! It is exactly what was a bit confusing: arrays and hashes (what else?) can be changed within a function without using $global: but normal variables cannot.

Comment: Basically you can change the contents of a referenced object (properties on an object, elements in an array, elements in a hashtable).  What you can't change without use `$global:<varname>` is the actual object (array/hashtable) the variable references.