# Global variables: Arrays not behaving like other variables

Tags: debugging, powershell, global-variables

I have a PowerShell script that is made up of a main PS1 file that then loads a number of Modules. In one of those modules I define a variable **$global:locationsXml** and then proceed to add to it without the global flag, and it works great. I can reference it without the global flag from any other module.
However, I also define a **$global:loadedDefinitions = @()** array and add to it. But I have to refer to this variable with the global flag when adding to it with +=. I can reference it in any other module without the global flag, but in the creating module I need it. And that module is the same one where the xml variable works differently/correctly.
I also have a Hash Table that I define without the global flag, but in the top level script that loads all the modules, and that I can reference without the global flag from anywhere. Additionally I have tried initializing the problem array in the parent script, like the Hash Table, but still the array requires the global flag in the module that populates it. But NOT in a different module that just reads it.
All of this is currently being tested in Windows 7 and PS 2.0.
So, before I go tearing things apart I wonder; is there a known bug, where global arrays behave differently from other global variables, specifically when being written to in a module?
I guess including the global flag for writing to the few arrays I need won't be a big deal, but I would like to understand what is going on, especially if it is somehow intended behavior rather than a bug.

Edit: To clarify, this works

```
Script:
 Define Hash Table without global specifier;
 Load Module;
 Call Function in Module;
  Read and write Hash Table without global specifier;
```

And this works

```
Script:
  Load Module;
  Call Function in Module;
    Initialize Array with global specifier;
    Append to Array with global specifier;
  Reference Array from anywhere else WITHOUT global specifier;
```

This doesn't

```
Script:
  Load Module;
  Call Function in Module;
    Initialize Array WITH global specifier;
    Append to Array without global specifier;
  Reference Array from anywhere fails;
```

This approach, of only initializing the variable with the global specifier and then referencing without it works for other variables, but not for arrays, "seems" to be the behavior/bug I am seeing. It is doubly odd that the global specifier only needs to be used in the module where the Array is initialized, not in any other module. I have yet to verify if it is also just in the function where it is initialized, and/or just writing to the array, not reading.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24435745/powershell-global-variables-local-variables

Comment: Hmm, I think my scenario is a bit different. I am not passing any of the discussed variables, and I don't have any local variables of the same name. I'm going to edit the original post to clarify, since I can use returns there.

Comment: That's what I thought originally too, but what I discovered is that once a variable is global, then it is available within all scopes, and therefor doesn't need the global specifier any more. And in my case I am running everything as a script initiated from a shortcut, so the ISE isn't involved at all. As it is, I shouldn't need to use Global, I should be able to use Script level scope, but my understanding is that the (flawed?) way Modules are implemented requires global scope. If you aren't using modules then you don't need global scope.

Comment: I also need to look into later versions. It may be that this ability to reference global scope without the specifier is a bug itself, and V3 or later fixes it.

Comment: Tested, and it works in Win8.1/v4. Meaning reading a global variable without the global specifier works. I may test the write behavior, but since 80% of my customers are still on Windows 7 and won't be changing soon, or upgrading PowerShell either, it doesn't matter much if it does, I have to work around the issue.

Answer (score 1):

When you read from variable without scope specifier, PowerShell first look for variable in current scope, then, if find nothing, go to parent scope, until it find variable or reach the global scope. When you write to variable without scope specifier, PowerShell write that variable in current scope only.

```powershell
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest #To produce VariableIsUndefined error.
&{
    $global:a=1
    $global:a   #1
    $local:a    #  Error VariableIsUndefined.
    $a          #1 Refer to global, $a as no $a in current scope.
    $a=2        #  Create variable $a in current scope.
    $global:a   #1 Global variable have old value.
    $local:a    #2 New local variable have new value.
    $a          #2 Refer to local $a.
}
```

Calling object's methods, property's and indexer's accessors (including set accessors) only read from variable. Writing to object  is a different from writing to variable.

```powershell
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest #To produce VariableIsUndefined error.
&{
    $global:a=1..3
    $global:a-join',' #1,2,3
    $local:a -join',' #        Error VariableIsUndefined.
    $a       -join',' #1,2,3   Refer to global $a, as no $a in current scope.
    $a[0]=4;          #        Write to object (Array) but not to variable, variable only read here.
    $global:a-join',' #4,2,3   Global variable have different content now.
    $local:a -join',' #        And you still does not have local one.
    $a       -join',' #4,2,3   Refer to global $a, as no $a in current scope.
    $a+=5             #        In PowerShell V2 this is equivalents to $a=$a+5.
                      #        There are two reference to $a here.
                      #        First one refer to local $a, as it is write to variable.
                      #        Second refer to global $a, as no $a in current scope.
                      #        $a+5 expression create new object and you assing it to local variable.
    $global:a-join',' #4,2,3   Global variable have old value.
    $local:a -join',' #4,2,3,5 But now you have local variable with new value.
    $a       -join',' #4,2,3,5 Refer to local $a.
}
```

So if you want to write to global variable from non-global scope, then you have to use `global` scope specifier. But if you only want to read from global variable, which is not hided by local variable with same name, you may omit `global` scope specifier.

Comment: Dang, why am I unable to format a comment? Or, more likely, what am I missing that allows me to format comments? ;-) Anyway...
Hmm, what sort of voodoo do I have going on then, because in my parent script I have 
$Px = @{ 
    Version = '3.2.2' 
    Context = 'Machine' 
    ScriptPath = Split-Path $($script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) 
    ScriptName = $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name 
    Set = "" 
} 
And from any function in any module I can do $Px.Set = "Some Value" with no troubles. And it works that way in both v2 & v4.

Comment: Now, to make matters even more interesting, I have another Array, that is initialized empty with the global specifier in a different module, and I can read AND write to it from functions in any module. So it would seem it isn't an issue with Arrays specifically. The Array that works is initialized at the top of the Module, outside of any functions, so I tried using the same approach with my problem Array, and no joy. It is sure acting like I have an Array of the same name that is either local, or perhaps script scope, but damned if I can find it. Arg!!!

Comment: You should update your question with a working powershell sample to illustrate where writing to the array works and where it doesn't. When you add an element to your array like `$arr += $item` you're creating a new object and saving it in the `$arr` variable, which is created in the local-scope just like @PetSerAl has shown. The reason `$Px.Set = "lala"` works is because you're actually only reading the variable and not writing to a variable. You're reading the reference to the object, and modifying the object's property without saving anything to the variable itself = no scope issue.

Comment: Also, use backticks ` in comments to add codeblocks. For big samples, edit your question and insert it there. Comments should be short and sweet :)

Comment: I'll try to update the example with something more specific. But I have 10K+ lines of code across 2 PS1s and 3 module files, plus a ton of Functions, so not sure yet how to document the issue simply while still documenting it completely.
In the end, I wonder if the best practice isn't to just always use the global specifier. I was seeing the ability to use the specifier once as syntactic sugar, and maybe it's not as sweet as I had thought.

Comment: Well, I think I am going to need to build a little jig to provide an example of this behavior. But in the meantime it has become I think an academic question, as I am just switching to using **global:** in all cases. The more I think about it it's like not using aliases in scripts. Both shortcuts might make sense for one liners and ad hoc work, but scripts should be more verbose.

Comment: So, just in the interests of closure, the issue here was my not understanding that variables get copied into lower scopes. Given that in most cases I was either only using variables as constants, or when I was mutating an array I was then only reading from it in the same scope, so it looked like it worked. At the same time I switched a bunch of procedure calls with a ton of arguments to a splatting approach, and started using $PSBoundParameters where appropriate. MUCH nicer. ;)